# Allow folder access in c# for non admin users via application

Tags: c#, directory, permissions, controls

I have C# application that copies files in C drive to selected USB device, but the user running the application doesn't need to have access to C folder normally. So is it possible to do the copy by running the application with the current user?

Comment: No, I mean, if it were possible - it is obviously a security hole which can be abused.

Comment: You either need to give permissions to the user, or allow the user to run the application as another user with privileges to access those folders.

Comment: As a workaround, you could configure a Windows service or a periodic batch job to wait for commands generated by the application. Once they are issued, the service/job could execute them with elevated rights.